# Sql query in nodejs behaving weied

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am making a query for the minimum temperature from the weather data table where the date is 2021-12-24 and getting an error `unknown column date in where clause`

```
connection.query(
    `select min(temperature) from weather_data where date=2021-12-24`,
    (err, results, field) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(results);
        console.log(results);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: And what is the name of the column that holds the date? You also need `'` around your date e.g. `'2021-12-24'` but if you will vary this dynamically according to user input, you must use parameters

Comment: its dt. my bad. i have done a very bad mistake

Comment: Now i am getting min temperature as null why is that

Comment: there are no records for that date, or you didn;t surround the date in `'`. If the date includes a time as well it will also be a reason why "there is no data for that date", because a time is important in a date time. a date of '2021-12-24' is equivalent to midnight on that date. If the weather reading is saved with a date of even 1 millisecond past midnight, it is not the same, for similar reasons that `1.0` is not the same as `1.0000001`